# Existence of elastic nested queries affect other queries inside "should" clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I found a bug in my program due to the following query returning no results:

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'filter': [
        {
          'bool': {
            'should': [
              {
                'nested': {
                  'path': 'c',
                  'query': {
                    'term': {
                      'c.properties.d.e': 'x'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                'term': {
                  'a.b.keyword': 'x'
                }
              }
            ],
            'minimum_should_match': 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even though the 2nd (non nested) query returns results:

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        {
          'term': {
            'a.b.keyword': 'x'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the existence of another nested query in the `should` clause which doesn't match results, affect the overall query, even though another query in the `should` matches and I only need one match? How do I fix the query to match documents when the nested query doesn't match but the non nested query does?

Edit: I found the issue is caused by a bad mapping in one of the indexes I'm searching on (I'm searching on multiple indexes): RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [c]')

Is it possible to return results matching the term query despite the nested path error in one of the indexes?

Comment: `'c.properties.d.e'` looks wrong to me. Can you update it to `'c.d.e'` or `'c.d.e.keyword'`. If it not works please share the mapping of the index with me

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your query to use a bool query with a should clause for both the nested and non-nested queries separately:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "c",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "c.properties.d.e": "x"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "a.b.keyword": "x"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue is resulted from a mapping error, so my edit on the question!